# Derivative of Lattice Laplacian

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, numerical-linear-algebra, laplacian

The lattice Laplacian is defined as,

$$
\nabla_L^2x_j \equiv \frac{x_{j+1} - 2x_j + x_{j-1}}{a^2}
$$
where the lattice spacing, $a$, is a constant.

The derivative, with respect to $x_i$, then gives,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \nabla_L^2x_j = \frac{\delta_{i(j+1)} - 2\delta_{ij} + \delta_{i(j-1)}}{a^2}
=
\begin{cases}
a^{-2}\ &\text{for}\ i=j+1\\
-2a^{-2}\ &\text{for}\ i=j\\
a^{-2}\ &\text{for}\ i=j-1
\end{cases}
$$

I am not sure intuitively why this is the case. I expected the derivative of the laplacian to be a function rather than a piecewise constant?

Comment: To give some context the derivative of the gradient squared comes out as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}  \left(\nabla \right)^2= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} (x_i - x_{i-1})^2 = \frac{2}{a^2}\left( x_{j+1} + 2x_j - x_{j-1} \right)$ or if you make it symmetric, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(x_{i+1} - x_i)(x_i - x_{i-1})  = \frac{( x_{j+1} - x_j + x_{j-1}) - x_{j-2} - x_{j+2}}{a^2}$

Comment: can't be bothered to rewrite all the latex but I just noted I omitted the $x_i$ so in that comment $(\nabla)^2$ should be $(\nabla x_i)^2$ and anyone paying attention I also implicitly set $a=1$ and forgot to put it back in for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrete Laplacian is a vector valued function of several variables: its argument is $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, and the output is another vector.

The function is a linear one (Laplacian is a linear operator), so, its partial derivative with respect to any $x_i$ is a constant vector, specifically the vector in which three entries are  $1/a^2$ or $-2/a^2$, and the rest are zeros. This is no more surprising than the derivative of $g(x)=2x$ being constant.

Informally, this means that changing the value at the $i$th lattice point affects the Laplacian only at that point and its neighbors, and describes how it affects them.

Comment: ok thanks I was concerned that perhaps I had done something stupid. This is very interesting because in euclidean quantum field theory (i.e. a rotation to imaginary time) one can express the free field action integral (here in 1D) as $S = \int dt\ \frac{m}{2}\left( \dot{x}^2 + mx^2\right)= \int dt\ x(m^2 - \nabla^2_L)x$ so clearly you get a massive computational advantage in doing integration by parts to obtain the Laplacian form!

Answer (score 0):

$\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$You
can approach this problem in a *purely* matrix form using the [Up Shift Matrix.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix)

For example, for $\,n=3$
$$U = \m{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$$
Then the lattice vector could be written as
$$\eqalign{
y &= \left(\frac{U-2I+U^T}{a^2}\right)x \;\doteq\; Lx \\
}$$
This is a linear equation and the gradient with respect to $x$ is simply
$$\eqalign{
\p{y}{x} &= L \\\\
}$$
**NB:** If your lattice is circulant, then you may want to use a cyclic permutation instead of a shift, i.e.
$$U = \m{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}$$